# Can not able to get the location state when opened with "open link in a new tab" in react router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am using React Router, "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2" this is my react router version as per my package.json.

```
<Link target="_blank" to={{
     pathname="/page"
     state= {
       referrer: 12
      }
}}  rel='noopener noreferrer' >Page</Link>
```

So, when I clicked on the link it opens fine no issues but when I try to open the link in a new tab, I am not able to access the location state. is there any way to access the location state while doing so?
Pardon me if I made any grammatical errors.

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
<Link target="_blank" to={{
 pathname="/page"
 state= {
   referrer: 12
  }
}}  rel='noopener noreferrer'  target="_blank" >Page</Link>
```

Comment: What did you change in your answer?

Comment: add target="_blank"